# How can I detect camera movement on FPS games basaed on game replay vid?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I wonder if I can detect a FPS game player's camera movement by simply using his vid replay?

What I am trying to do are to:

1. get precise camera movement when player in scope mode
2. get relatively precise camera movement when people in casual mode

But the problems I am facing are:

1. the marksman line are blocking some area of the screen, which make it hard to align the pixels.
2. the gun/UI and some other elements in the UI make it even harder in casual mode than scope mode.

Hopefully I get my question correctly asked.

a simple sample of my prblem 1:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM8by.jpg

Comment: look into optical flow